# Where can I ask about fringe API recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am wondering where I would ask this kind of question (just an example)

> What service can do reverse-phonenumber searches for Germany?

The answers would be based on opinions, but would help me with my programming task. I assume this would be closed as such on SO. Because at the least, no code generally makes it a bad question.

Where would be the best place for this type of question instead? If I don't live in Germany, I won't know much about any state-run services, or anything else that isn't marketed much in foreign countries.

Answer (score 0):

Requests for broad product recommendations or generalized product/service reviews ("which is best?") can be somewhat problematic, so they are *not* generally allowed on *most* sites.

But if the problem is that you tried and failed in finding a solution to your very *specific* problem, your question may — just *may* — work on one of our sites ([Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) come to mind; see their help center for details).

**But please read that opening paragraph again.** Questions based on a premise of *"which one should I use…?"* or *"please list all the apps…"* are more likely to be closed that not. If you can make it ***very*** clear that you have failed in your solution search and you can describe a ***very SPECIFIC problem*** that can be answered authoritatively and completely in the space of a post, your question *should* be acceptable on one of the sites linked above (depending on what you want to ask).

The line between a good solution search and a request for reviews is subtle and fleeting, so take extra care when asking these questions. Many sites have taken the position that these are simply too much trouble and will just close them on sight.

Comment: That question will be closed on Web Apps.